# UIDatePicker Selected value is wrong in case UIDatePicker was not scrolled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidatepicker

[image]

I am making an iPhone app in which I am using `UIDatePicker` and displaying the selected the time in a actionsheet. In actionsheet the time is displaying with 10 mints interval.

`textfield` value is set correctly when I do scroll the **`Datepicker`**

If I  **don't** scroll the action sheet then direct click on select button then text field set the current time (**`11:56`**)  but I select in action sheet (**`11:50`**) time. (`textfield`) shows the incorrect value.

How can I set the `textfield`'s value (`11:50`). Give me some solution.

Comment: nslog your selected value ie youdatepicker.date

Comment: select [12:30] and nslog  12:37 if i don't scroll .... and if i scroll then [selcet 12:30] ..  nslog 12:30

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** 
Make your class to handle UIControlEventValueChanged event in your picker. Add this line ViewDidLoad method or when your actionsheet shown:

```
  [picker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) 
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Now selector would be called when date is changed

**UPDATE**

```
- (void) dateChanged:(id)sender{
    // handle date changes and set in textField
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSString *strdate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date]; //provide your selected date here
    self.dateTexField.text = strdate;
}
```

If above method is not called means date is not changed so always set default date in your textField.

---

Convert date to string object

**UPDATE**

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 NSString *strdate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date]; //provide your selected date here
```

Now set value to textField like this:

```
  self.dateTextField.text = strdate;
```

Comment: i do this .. this will work correct when i scroll . but not in the  case when i directly tap on the select  Button

Answer (score 1):

Just set the dateSelected from your date picker after select button press....

```
NSDate *date = datePicker.date;
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];    
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
yourTxtField.text = dateString;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is just to attach a toolbar with a done button to your TextField that has the UIDatePicker as its inputView. Keep track of your current TextField by maintaining a reference to it in TextViewDidBeginEditing. Then in the done button do something like this:

```
if (_currentTextField == _myTextFieldThatUsesADatePicker) {
    self.myDateProperty = _myDatePicker.date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this way correct wrong but its working for me

```
-(void)selectedTime{
    NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//    [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
    [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    selectedTime = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
    NSArray *temp=[selectedTime componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    NSLog(@"%@",temp);
    NSInteger mins=[[temp objectAtIndex:1]integerValue];
    //check your interval here
    if (mins<=29) {
        selectedTime=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@:%@",[temp objectAtIndex:0],@"00",@"00"];
    }else if (mins>=31 && mins<=59){
        selectedTime=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@:%@",[temp objectAtIndex:0],@"30",@"00"];
    }else{
//        selectedTime = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
    }
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(SelectedValue:)]) {
        [self.delegate SelectedValue:selectedTime];
    }
    [self.popupController dismiss];
}
```

My interval is **30 mins**